# How to add a addition one value in to devexpress grid pager dropdown in asp.net c#?

Tags: asp.net

I want to add a addtional value "ALL" into devExpress grid pager dropdown.Default display following setting

```
    <PageSizeItemSettings Items="10,20,50,100" Visible="True">
     </PageSizeItemSettings>
```

I want to add one addition value All into PageSizeItemSettings  dropdown.When i clicked on All it should display all the table row. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution related display All option in pager.